# Is wordpress allow to pause user registration?

Tags: php, wordpress

My client want a functionality that Admin can pause registration  from admin panel.

I have RND on it but i could not found anything. so it's possible or not orelse can we do by custom or not?

Is wordpress providing any plugin ?

does anyone know then please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use disable user registration plugin to stop registering user.
Following plugin will help you
https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-user-registration/